# How to navigate to the same tab after submitting a form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, filter, tabs

I have a form to filter data from the database. I am  using PHP and a MySQL for doing that. Now the problem I have is that as soon as I press the "go>>" button it redirects to the first tab i.e  "Surname Details" and displays the result in second tab i.e. "Search". How can I navigate to the "Search" tab by default?

CODE:

```
<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"> <a href="#home1" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true"> <i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;surname Details</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#search" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home1"> you are in the surname details tab </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="search" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
  <div class="col-md-3">

  <!--left div for displaying the form --> 
  <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
    <b>Select Surname: <br />
    </b>
    <select name="search" required="required"  autofocus="autofocus">
      <option value="select1">select1 </option>
      <option value="select2">select2</option>
      <option value="select3">select</option>
    </select>
    <b>Select Martial Status:</b>
    <select name="mstat" >
      <option value="">Select </option>
      <option value="Y">Married</option>
      <option value="N">Unmarried</option>
    </select>
    <strong>Select Gender:</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="f" required id="gender_0" />
Female
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="m" required id="gender_1" />
Male
    <b>Enter age range</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="fage" size="2">    to    <input type="text" name="tage" size="2">
    <input type="submit"  value=">>go" >
  </form>
</div>

<!--right div for displaying the result -->
<div class="col-md-9">
  The Result(s) found for the surname<?php echo $searchq;?></b>, marital status<?php echo $searchmstat;?>  gender<?php echo $searchgender;?> of age between<?php echo $searchfage;?> <?php echo $searchtage;?>is: <?php echo $output;?> 
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sioFH.png)

I would prefer a PHP solution if possible as I'm not familiar with AJAX and Javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would help if we had an idea on how you're doing the tab switching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go ahead and assume that you're using bootstrap tabs. You can change the open tab at the following part of the HTML:

```
<?php 
     $tabToOpen = 1; //Or change to 2 under some condition
 ?>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade <?= $tabToOpen==1?"in":"" ?> active" id="home1"> you are in the surname details tab </div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade <?= $tabToOpen==2?"in":"" ?> " id="search" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
```